# Error on Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a asp.net MVC application and I am experiencing a weird error after rendering the Html.BeginForm().

Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateData", "Assurity", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))        
        {            
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @for = "firstName", @class = "label_16 col-sm-2 control-label" })                        
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control input-lg label_16", @placeholder = @Resources.PSI.FirstNamePlaceHolder })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null, new { @class = "label_16" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @for = "Surname", @class = "label_16 col-sm-2 control-label" })                        
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control input-lg label_16", @placeholder = @Resources.PSI.SurnamePlaceHolder })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Surname, null, new { @class = "label_16" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer_30 clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
            <div class="spacer_10 clearfix visible-xs"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xlg btn-responsive label_18 label_900_White_shadow" >CONFIRM</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

It renders an html like:

```
<form action="/" class="form-horizontal" method="post">            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label_16 col-sm-2 control-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>                        
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg label_16" data-val="true" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="Enter here your first name" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid label_16" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label_16 col-sm-2 control-label" for="Surname">Surname</label>                        
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg label_16" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Surname field is required." id="Surname" name="Surname" placeholder="Enter here your surname" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid label_16" data-valmsg-for="Surname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer_30 clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
            <div class="spacer_10 clearfix visible-xs"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xlg btn-responsive label_18 label_900_White_shadow">CONFIRM</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

So, why is the form rendered without controller and action name? What is wrong with this code?

UPDATE:

```
public virtual ActionResult ValidateData()
        {
            return View(MVC.Assurity.Views.DefaultPSI, new PSIViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult> ValidateData(PSIViewModel vm)
        {
```

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults:
                new
                {
                    controller = MVC.Assurity.Name,
                    action = MVC.Assurity.ActionNames.ValidateData,
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
```

Comment: this is beacuse `ValidateData` and `Assurity` is your default controller and action...just check it in `RouteConfig.cs` file inside `App_Start` folder.

Comment: That's true, but then why to I get a "Message: The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'." after doing a post?

Comment: do you have a httppost controller action in your controller which will handle post request?

Comment: and just for testing purpose instead of `<button type="submit" ...` use `<input type="submit" ...`

Comment: Yes I do have an httppost action. I changed the button to input and the result is the same

Comment: well i am not familiar with the error mesage you are getting but i think you are using attribute routing in your project and that is creating the problem try using `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` attribute in your httppost controller action

Comment: Using [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] the result is the same. Could It be a problem in the version of some assembly?

Comment: post controller action and routeconfig code also.

Comment: Why is the controller marked as virtual ? Could this be causing a problem ?